# Decode Animated WebP using Javascript (React / NextJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webp, next.js13, animated-webp

I'm trying to **decode animated WebP images**.
I'd like to **extract** the **frames** composing the animation as well as the **delay** for each frame.

Any idea of how to deal with decoding animated WebP images using **JavaScript in a React / NextJS environment**?

I've found node-webpmux (https://github.com/ApeironTsuka/node-webpmux), which is webpmux (https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/webpmux?hl=es-419) for JavaScript. However, it's incompatible as it first tries to use the FS and crashes on Browsers, being incompatible with React / NextJS.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently working with the framework, I'm seeing some issues with my frames for animates webP, but works fine!

I can share my code in NodeJS:

```
const WebpImage = require('node-webpmux').Image;
...
    const webPImage = await new WebpImage();
await webPImage.load(file);

if (webPImage.hasAnim) {
  const maxFrames = this.isReduceQuality() ? 1 : 3;

  if (webPImage.frames !== undefined && webPImage.frames.length > 1) {
    /**
     * Available frames for webp image.
     */
    const frames = [...webPImage.frames];

    /**
     * Evaluate to reduce the number of frames for the image.
     */
    const reduce = Math.round(webPImage.frames.length / maxFrames);

    /**
     * Cleaning frames for webp image.
     */
    webPImage.frames.splice(0, webPImage.frames.length);

    /**
     * Pushing webp image frames.
     */
    frames.forEach((frame, index) => {
      if (index % reduce === 0) {
        frame.delay = 300;
        webPImage.frames.push(frame);
      }
    });
  }

  return sharp(await webPImage.save(null), options);
```

Comment: Could you use on React before the last upgrade? There was a fix last week, before that, it was not possible.

Comment: Hello @yondur o/
I'm using NodeJS-Express with the node-webpmux package to remove some frames from the webp image, mostly for business purposes, but I'm still seeing errors from one of the image with removed chunks.